# The Claw of my Mesh deforms when I bend the Armature

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

Any clue as to why this is happening?

The claws and the pads are all weight painted red. Here is my link Do you have any solutions

Here is a link if you need more info https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q45-Xk_Mt_fwbmZFbHyrrMJZLnvQDvcW

[image: random screenshot of Blender UI]

Answer (score 0):

there must a vertex group (a mesh) assigned to that bone and it makes it bend, be sure to check how are assigned all your vertex groups after parenting, also lucks wrong tilted that bone, in the right panel appears an option for that called "tilt" then you can fix it, also rotating in the local axis might work too.

Comment: I'm relatively new to blender, I don't know half of what you said

Comment: hmm i see.... try watching more rigging videos as posible  of blender obviously for you may understand what i said